# loop to create multiple dataframes out of one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to make a loop that will output into multiple dataframes from one large dataframe.

```
raw_df['names'] = [joe, joe, bob, john, john]
raw_df['order_id'] = [10, 12, 5, 20, 25]
raw_df['amount'] = [100, 1000, 200, 20 25]

for name in raw_df['name'].unique():
    names = pd.DataFrame(raw_df.loc[raw_df['name'] == name])
    name['cummulative_sum'] = owner_names['amount'].cumsum()
```

Expected outcome for all names: `joe.head()`

```
name   id   sum
joe    10   100    
joe    12   110
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking for each unique item, it's possible to do `.groupby` on the variable of interest:

```py
for group_name, group_df in raw_df.groupby("name"):
   print("Processing name:", group_name)
   names = group_df # this is the same as "names" in your snippet
   names["cum_sum"] = names["amount"].cumsum()
```

The `group_df` is the same df one would get with `raw_df.loc[raw_df['name'] == name]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
variables = locals()

for name, data in raw_df.groupby('names'):
    variables[name] = data
 
joe
Out[607]: 
  names  order_id  amount
0   joe        10     100
1   joe        12    1000
```